# Verifying the convergence of distribution and find the distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, inference, moment-generating-function

Let $X_n$ =
\begin{cases} 
      \mu & \text{With probability } \frac{1}{2} \\
      \mu + \frac{1}{n} & \text{With probability } \frac{1}{2}  \\
\end{cases}

Use the method of moment generating functions to verify that $X_n \xrightarrow{D}X$ and find the distribution of $X$.

I know the method of moment generating functions states when we have $t\in(-h,h)$ and $X$ is a random variable with moment-generating function $M_x(t)$ which exists for $|t|\le h_1 <h$, then if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}M_{x_n}(t) = M_x(t), \forall |t| \le h_1$$
then $X_n \xrightarrow{D}X$. And I know that $M_{x_n}(t) = E(e^{tx_n}))$, but how can I don't know how to find $M_{x_n}(t)$.

Lastly, how do I find the distribution of $X$?

Any help regarding these issues is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It  should be fairly clear what $X$  has to  be, but  the answer  will also come out of the computations.   For  the  mgf: you know  the distribution of $x_n$, so take it in steps  you can write down the distribution of  $tx_n$ and then of $e^{tx_n}$ and then compute its mean

Comment: Do you know how to compute the expectation for a random variable? Specifically, the random variable $e^{tX_n}$ that equals $e^{t\mu}$ with probability $1/2$, and otherwise equals $e^{t(\mu+1/n)}$.